# Laravel 5 ResetsPasswords for JWTAuth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using JWT Authentication and I am trying to setup a Reset Password api functionality using ResetsPasswords.

I have created my own controller for reseting the password to use ResetsPasswords:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Models\PdTlogin;
use App\Models\PdTprofessional;
use App\Models\PdTpatientPainkiller;
use App\Models\PdTprofessionalQualifcation;
use App\Models\PdTprofessionalSpeciality;
use Config;
use LbTtradesman_login;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use ResetsPasswords;

    public function resetPassword(request $request)
    {
        return json_encode($this->reset($request));
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

And I am calling the reset function in ResetsPasswords, here is that full controller:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        //$this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
            : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);


    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->forceFill([
            'password' => bcrypt($password),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
        ])->save();

        $this->guard()->login($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse($response)
    {
    return trans($response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return ['email' => trans($response)];
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('pd_tlogin');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

But when I run everything, my password does not get updated. Instead I get this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\v1\ResetPasswordController::resetPassword() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\User given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php
>   on line 45

I really don't understand this error or what I am doing wrong :( All I know is that my User model is `App\Models\PdTlogin` with the database table name of `pd_tlogin`

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this:

```
public function resetPassword(request $request)
     {   
        $this->validate($request, [
                'token' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]); 
        $credentials = $request->only(
                'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );  
        $response = $this->passwords->reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
                $user->password = bcrypt($password);
                $user->save();
                $this->auth->login($user);
        }); 
        return json_encode($response);
     }
```

But I got this error:

> Undefined property:
>   App\Http\Controllers\v1\ResetPasswordController::$passwords',
>   '/var/www/html/my_project/app/Http/Controllers/v1/ResetPasswordController.php

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel 5 is the version I am using

Comment: In resetPassword have a typo error Use Request $request

Comment: Fixed the typo, still does not work :(

Comment: `$response = $this->**passwords**->reset(` passwords or password ?

Comment: Why did you re-write reset method again ? You could have used the method in the `ResetsPasswords` trait, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It seems you need a `json` resonse from the `reset` method. Modify your `ResetPasswordController` as,

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
//...

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    protected function sendResetResponse($response)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => trans($response)]);
    }

    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => trans($response)], 401);
    }

    // removed min:6 validation
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ];
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

And point your reset route to `ResetPasswordController@reset`.

Comment: I don't understand....Im kinda new to Laravel and JWTAuth, what should my resetPassword method look like?

Comment: When you use a trait in a class, it extends the functionality of that class. So, `ResetsPasswords` trait has the built in `reset()` method already which you can use on the fly. But in your case, you need a `json` response from the `reset()` method. By default, the `reset()` method do a redirect after the reset. That's why I extended the response methods in your own controller to return `json` responses.

Comment: And the `ResetsPasswords` trait will take case of the rest.

Comment: Trying this now.

Comment: Okay, I modified my code and added the sendResetResponse, sendResetFailedResponse and rules method and my resetPassword method only has this `return json_encode($this->reset($request));` however I am getting this error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\v1\ResetPasswordController::resetPassword() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\User given

Comment: What's the method you are using in the route? Your `resetPassword()` is no longer required since you have to use the trait's `reset()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182510/discussion-between-ijas-ameenudeen-and-user979331).

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking resetPassword of the **ResetPasswordController** instead of invoking resetPassword of the **ResetPasswords** trait. Change the resetPassword function name in your controller or use an alias for the trait resetPassword function like this:

```
    use ResetsPasswords
    {
        resetPassword as protected resetUserPassword;
    }
```

Comment: Trying this now.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\v1\ResetPasswordController::$passwords

Comment: That is because you are trying to reference passwords property that doesn't exists on your controller.What if you try the prior version of your controller?  public function resetPassword(request $request)
    {
        return json_encode($this->reset($request));
    }

Comment: Okay, I tried that with my original code and got the first original error `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\v1\ResetPasswordController::resetPassword() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\User given, called in /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php on line 45`

Answer (score 0):

```
return response()->json(['message'=> __('labels.password_updated')]);
```